# jQuery offset() wrong

Tags: jquery, offset

I have an issue on a site, I think is a CSS issue, but really can't figure it out.

I'm using jQuery to get the position of a div image container. When the mouse hovers on it, a hidden form should appear, relative to the div image container. The hidden form popups correctly, but in the wrong position, like if offset() got wrong values.

This is the JS jQuery code (id is a parameter of my js function)

```
var currentTarget = jQuery(id);
var pos = currentTarget.offset();

container.css('top', parseInt(pos.top) + 'px');
container.css('left', parseInt(pos.left) + 'px');
```

And this is the site http://www.disegnosis.com.ar/rentalstation/

Thanks alot in advise

Comment: `offset()` cannot be read from hidden fields - http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: The code is executed from an onmouseover function triggered by a visible DIV tag, so the code "var currentTarget = jQuery(id);" gets the dom object of that div by it ID and calculates the offset via, offset() function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read offset coordinates of hidden elements.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

The common workaround is to momentarily make the element visible, grab the offset coordinates, then hide it again.

Comment: The code is executed from an onmouseover function triggered by a visible DIV tag, so the code "var currentTarget = jQuery(id);" gets the dom object of that div by it ID and calculates the offset via, offset() function.